# typescript: error TS1056 and TS2304 Cannot find name Iterable - SignalR .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr

I am new to SignalR, so I tried to follow a tutorial on the Microsoft site [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

I used *Add Client-Side Library* to project and added an unpkg: `@aspnet/signalr@1.0.4`

When I build I get lots of errors complaining about the `lib` being changed to target `es2015` or higher.  After reading a few things on this site, I found that I may need a `tsconfig.json` in the route of my project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise"
    ]
  }
}
```

This seemed to have got rid of the `promise` errors, but I faced with TS1056 and TS2304 errors:

[image]

I'm not sure if I am doing things right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this into your csproj file so you can build your code

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, this got rid of all the compilation errors.  However, I'm having difficulty referencing the files in `wwwroot` in the `view`.  I'll post a new question for this.

Comment: Give me a link of your new question I will have a look

Comment: Thanks, it is here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987367/problems-referencing-static-javascript-files-in-wwwroot-net-core-2-2-signalr/57987429#57987429`