# Problems referencing static JavaScript files in wwwroot - .Net Core 2.2 Signalr

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I'm having difficulty referencing the relevant `js` files for `signalr` from the `wwwroot` folder.

The paths I need to reference are:

- wwwroot/lib/@aspnet/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js
- wwwroot/js/chat.js

Here is my view:

```
@page
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-6">
            User..........<input type="text" id="userInput" />
            <br />
            Message...<input type="text" id="messageInput" />
            <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/wwwroot/lib/@@AspNetCore/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/wwwroot/js/chat.js"></script>
```

I am getting 404's in the browser:

> http://localhost:5005/wwwroot/lib/@AspNetCore/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js
>   404 (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:5005/wwwroot/js/chat.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not
>   Found)

**Update**

After changing my script paths I am faced with these errors in the browser:

http://localhost:5005/lib/@AspNetCore/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught ReferenceError: signalR is not defined at chat.js:3

`chat.js` Line 3:

`var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();`

This has red squiggly lines under it.

Comment: You don't actually include the `wwwroot` portion in the URL. That's dynamically mapped to the document root.

Comment: Ah I did wonder why it was not needed. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you change a folder name and replace a url like this

```
<script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

Check this link [too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Note: make sure your code is place at bottom of the page

Comment: Ah no, where does that code go?  When you say change the folder names, do you mean going into Windows Explorer and changing the folder structure i.e. delete the `@Aspnetcore` folder?

Comment: Yes. Put your signalr library code into `signalr` folder. I never reference a script from a folder that have special character like that

Comment: Ok will do that, but where does that `import` code go?

Comment: Thanks, yes that's the exact tutorial I have been following and I can't get it to work, or see where your previous `import` statement goes.  I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: I dont think you need the import because you are just using js not es6 code. What error you have right now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199609/discussion-between-tony-ngo-and-user1574598).

Comment: Ok, just opened the chat now.

Answer (score 2):

1st, you should make sure your app (kestrel server) support static file (`app.UseStaticFiles()` in Configurate method in `startup.cs`) , and make sure the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment.WebRoot` is to a folder in your disk（normally it point to `$"{Dictory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/wwwroot/"`）.

2st, make sure your signalr.js is in `WebRoot` folder (so it can be serve), and note  the `wwwroot` folder is your root path eg `~/`, which mean your your js file is in `wwwroot/lib/signalr/signalr.js` the correct path for razor's **script Tag Helper** is `<script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="~/wwwroot/lib/@@AspNetCore/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/wwwroot/js/chat.js"></script>
```

Replace with this

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/@@AspNetCore/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I replaced them lines and I still get a 404 ` http://localhost:5005/lib/@AspNetCore/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` then an Uncaught ReferenceError `signalR is not defined` at `chat.js:3` which is this line of code: `var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();`

Comment: If you are writing in the View file. Try wrap scripts into section. Edited answer above

Comment: Once I get it working I'll stick the scripts at the bottom of a `_SiteMaster.cshtml`